# Cosa significa "il più vago smalto" in questa frase?

Tags: meaning

Nel libro *Racconto d'autunno*, di Tommaso Landolfi, ho letto la frase seguente:

> Le foglie gialle d'una cascia lì
>   presso facevano **il più vago smalto** col cielo azzurro.

Nel [dizionario Garzanti](https://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=cascia) ho trovato che una "cascia" è una "acacia". Non capisco però il significato di "smalto" in questa frase, malgrado abbia cercato questo termine in parecchi dizionari, soprattutto perché è qualificato con la locuzione "il più vago". Potreste spiegarmelo?

Comment: È possibile secondo me che  intenda che le foglie "dipingevano" il cielo con il loro giallo creando un contrasto di colore.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: L'espressione "il più vago smalto" però non mi fa pensare a un contrasto.

Comment: A volte “smalto” significa “vivacità” (http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/S/smalto.shtml). “Vago”, oltre al significato di “indefinito, impreciso”, ha quello (letterario) di “bello” (http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/V/vago_1.shtml). La frase, molto alta e letteraria, può dunque significare che i due colori insieme davano un’idea di bella vivacità.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Interpretando, come ha segnalato Benedetta, "vago" come "bello", la tua spiegazione ha più senso.

Comment: @Benedetta: Potresti scriverlo come risposta?

Comment: @Charo: lo faccio subito.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A volte, in senso figurato, "[smalto](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/S/smalto.shtml)" significa "vivacità".

"[Vago](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/V/vago_1.shtml)", oltre al significato di "indefinito, impreciso", ha quello (letterario) di "bello".

La frase, molto alta e letteraria, può dunque significare che i due colori insieme davano un'idea di bella vivacità.